# How to redirect a certain input string to an executable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, redirect

In Linux it is very easy to start a cgi program from a batch file with a certain standard input:

```
echo "name=john&city=abc" | mycgiprogram
```

Now I want to do the same in a batch file.

I learned already that in the Windows cmd.exe shell you have to write "start" to start an executable file:

```
start mycgiprogram
```

But how is it possible to transfer a certain input string as in the above linux example to the cgi program?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You can pipe output from one command to another command the same way in a batch file.

Comment: The solution on Windows:  `echo "name=john&city=abc" | mycgiprogram`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo name=john^&city=abc | mycgiprogram
```

No quotes, as those will be echo'd, too. You need to escape the `&`, so it will not be interpreted by the command shell.

You do not need `start` to run a program, that would be resembling the appended `&` in unix, in that it starts the program in parallel in a separate shell.